# MVC form with required field as drop down list OR create new value

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, frameworks, modal-dialog, entity

I have an entity framework, code first, MVC form for creating a ToDo model.
The ToDo form has a drop down list where users has to select the required Client.

```
public class ToDo
{
     [Key]
     public int ToDoId {get;set;}
     [Required]
     public int ClientId {get;set;}
     public string TaskDescription {get;set;}
}

public class Client
{
     [Key]
     public int ClientId {get;set;}
     public string ClientName {get;set;}
     public string AddressLine1 {get;set;}
     public string AddressLine2 {get;set;}       
}
```

I want to be able to offer the option of adding a new Client from the same screen and not lose and ToDo information that might have been input already.

I have tried posting the current ticket data to a separate action and returning a partial view to a modal with a client form.
But on submitting the Client form, because the data passed to the action has to also be a ToDo model (if I want to pre-populate the ToDo form on return)
the ModelState is still validating against the ToDo object and not the Client object.

I am obviously approaching this all wrong but I can't find any information for my scenario on the web.

Comment: A typical approach is to have a popup form, which makes an ajax post to create the new record, and in the success callback, add the option to your `<select>` element

Comment: Thanks for this. I've had to move on to another project but should be able to look at this again next week.

Comment: Thank Stephen, your advise and a break from the project has led to me getting this done. The thing I was neglecting to come to terms with was I wasn't stuck with returning only Json or only a partial view. I can in fact pick and choose depending on the situation. If the client is added correctly I can send back a json object with any info I need to update my original form before closing the model. Or if the post didn't work out, I can send back a partial view with the original model for a retry.